# Angularjs binding array element ng-repeat in directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to display the elements of an array using ng-repeat and a directive. The directive part is important to the solution. However the element of the array is not getting bound and displays an empty value.

The fiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/qrdk9sp5/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{chat.words}}
    <test ng-repeat="word in chat.words"></test>    
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.chat = {
        words: [
            'Anencephalous', 'Borborygm', 'Collywobbles'
        ]
    };
});
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            word: '='
        },
        template: "<li>{{word}}</li>",
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {}
    }
});
```

OUTPUT

```
["Anencephalous","Borborygm","Collywobbles"]
•
•
•
```

Expected output

```
["Anencephalous","Borborygm","Collywobbles"]
•Anencephalous
•Borborygm
•Collywobbles
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't bind `word`.

You have used isolate scope. If you don't bind with it's `scope` property,it won't work.

```
scope: {
    word: '='
},
```

Try like this

```
<test word="word" ng-repeat="word in chat.words"></test>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/uhwyw1ga/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('dr', []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.chat= {words: [
      'Anencephalous', 'Borborygm', 'Collywobbles'
    ]};
});
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            word: '='
        },
        priority: 1001,
        template: "<li>{{word}}</li>",
        replace: true,        
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {             
        }
    }
});
```

Your directive needs to run before ng-repeat by using a higher priority, so when ng-repeat clones the element it is able to pick your modifications.

The section "Reasons behind the compile/link separation" from the [Directives user guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) have an explanation on [how ng-repeat works](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L149).

The current ng-repeat priority is 1000, so anything higher than this should do it.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to the code? Why will this solve the issue?